# How can a set the same space between paragraph and table in Word?

Tags: table-styles, microsoft-word-2019

I have a specific spacing configuration between paragraphs and tables, as is shown in figure 1. However, the actual before and after spaces are quite different (see red and blue arrows). I would like to have the same before and after space results (see figure 2).

figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

figure 2
[image: Figure 2]

I have been doing some experiments, and it is not clear how Word controls the spacings

(figure 3)

[image: Figure 3]

I want to have **"visible uniform spacing"** between paragraphs and tables in such a way that my equations inside tables look evenly spaced (same before and after space).

Here is a sample document: [sample_document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5nudrx84t2gh5m/PhD_proposal.docx?dl=0)

Comment: Please add a tag including your Word version.

Comment: A sample document would be helpful. Here is my article on the Microsoft website on how to provide a link. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either 1. adjust the spacing of the paragraph before or paragraph after the table, or 2. change the positioning of the table.

For the 1st method, You will need to change your spacing before and spacing per paragraph. They might not all have the same before or after spacing.

For the 2nd case, right-click on the table, select Table Properties -> Around -> Positioning, then set the Top and Bottom settings for "Distance from surrounding text". The caveats with this method is that the table will be acting like inserted objects, and your texts might go around it if/when you add texts.

[image]